# In angular cli with webpack how can you turn off the typescript linting on ng serve

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, angular-cli

In angular cli with webpack how can you turn off the typescript linting on ng serve

I get some silly errors that I need to be skipped.

Is their any angular cli setting I can do to turn off typescript being checked?

This is the app im using: https://github.com/2sic/app-tutorial-angular4-hello-dnn

**This is my angular cli json file:**

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "my-app"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico",
        "favicon16.ico",
        "favicon16.png",
        "favicon32.ico",
        "favicon32.png",
        "favicon96.png",
        "humans.txt",
        "robots.txt",
        "sitemap.xml"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.scss"
      ],
      "scripts": [          
        "resources/jquery.js",
        "resources/jquery-ui.js",
        "resources/bootstrap.js",
        "resources/externalScripts.js",
        "resources/lodash.js",
        "resources/moment.js",    
        "resources/amcharts.js",  
        "resources/amcharts-pie.js",
        "resources/amcharts-light.js",
        "resources/firebase.js",
        "node_modules/@agm/core/core.umd.js",
        "node_modules/angular2-google-maps/core/core.umd.js"
      ],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "scss",
    "component": {
    }
  }
}
```

This is the git bash typescript errors I want to ignore.

[image]

Comment: Try removing the lint section from the `.angular-cli.json`.

Comment: Thanks il try that

Comment: @R.Richards I still get type errors when I run ng serve. I've now attached my git bash errors and my angular cli json file above.

Comment: ive done an ng eject to see the webpack.config.js file - is there anything I can do in that file?

Comment: Those are not lint errors, those are "actual" angular/typescript errors

Comment: @echonax can I skip them some how and still run the app?

Comment: No, you cannot skip them. You need to fix the errors if you want the application to work. It is this compile time error checking that keeps you from delivering buggy code.