# PhpStorm WebStorm angular-cli project; how to turn off lint

Tags: angular, phpstorm, webstorm, angular-cli, tslint

I'm running `PhpStorm 2017.2`, and I created an `angular-cli` project in a folder that already some modules and components built with `angular-cli`.

I get thousands of linting errors that are making it impossible for me to quickly find and address actual Typescript errors. I would like to disable linting until I've dealt with serious errors but I don't know how.

In accordance with the advice [given here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43402803/in-angular-cli-with-webpack-how-can-you-turn-off-the-typescript-linting-on-ng-se), I've tried to delete the tslint section from `.angular-cli.json`, then restart the PhpStorm software. However, I'm still getting the linting errors (eg: "*Comment must start with a space*"

Why is linting still happening, and how can I disable it until I'm finished addressing actual TS errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Your IDE, you need to go to Preferences (I use WebStorm), select the section TypeScript and TSLint and uncheck the Enable box (see attached screenshot.[image])

Comment: For Windows/Linux users, instead of Preferences go to file -> settings